# How to return as observer from localStorage or an other observer in Angular2?

Tags: angular, local-storage, observers, angular2-localstorage

Here is my "loantype" service get() function:

```
get() {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    let response;
    if ( localStorage.getItem('loantypes_are_valid') === '1' ) {
      response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loantypes') || '[]');
    } else {
      response = this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
        localStorage.setItem('loantypes', JSON.stringify(result) );
        localStorage.setItem('loantypes_are_valid', '1');
      });
    }
    return response;
  });
}
```

I just want to use this service something like this:

```
this.loanTypes.get().subscribe(
  response => this.loantypes = response,
  (error: AppError) => {throw error; }
);
```

Now, the goal is to serve the datas from localStorage if it's valid, otherwise I need to reload it from the API server, store it into the localStorage (for the next requests) and serve the datas into the component.

This code store the datas into the localStorage, and after this happening something wrong and I can't figure out what is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: When you say, something is wrong, what is it?

Comment: I get back an observable object, not a JSON object with the datas...

Comment: You want an Observable, right? And did you try adding a return under the Subscription?

Comment: yes, but in the second part of my example code I want get a JSON object into the `this.loantypes` ... how can I do this?

Comment: The `response` under the second part will be a JSON object itself, because we are subscribing the Observable there. You don't get it as JSON?

Comment: No, it's still an Observable object. How can I convert it?

Comment: Can you do this? (response) => {console.log(response); this.loantypes = response} under the subscription?

Comment: See, if the updated answer works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169279/discussion-between-netdjw-and-ashish-ranjan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try adding a return statement under subscription</strike>

```
localStorage.setItem('loantypes', JSON.stringify(result) );
localStorage.setItem('loantypes_are_valid', '1');
return result
```

Call the Observer's next()

```
 if () {
   observer.next(JSON.parse(...))
 }
 else {
    response = this.getAll().subscribe(result => {
       localStorage.setItem('loantypes', JSON.stringify(result) );
       localStorage.setItem('loantypes_are_valid', '1');
       observer.next(result) 
    });
 }
observer.complete()
```